# Why doesn't the flow of current through the conductors in the rotor of a fan affect it?

Tags: motors

[image]

The rotor of fan is shown as a series of circles arranged in a circular manner. From youtube videos, I came to know that this is sort of a top view and the circles actually represent conductors through which current 'can' flow into the screen or come out of the screen (towards the viewers). 
I wonder as to what happens to the current that arises in these conductors (due to the induction of EMF).

Where do the electrons flow to ? There has got to be some path, which makes that path a conductor, and hence susceptible to be affected by lorentz force.

So why isn't that shown ?
(Diagrams would be highly helpful)

Comment: Google "induction motor".  The rotor is a so-called "squirrel cage", with bars running parallel to the axis (the circles in the diagram above), that are shorted to rings at each end of the rotor.

Comment: That is also highly helpful. Never occured in my mind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each of the circles or conductors are actually paired with another, probably diametrically opposite but this is not always the case.

So, if the current is coming towards you on one circle then it will be going away from you on its pair.

That is the path you are looking for as the linking connections are not shown as that diagram is a section drawn through the rotor.

Comment: I thought so. But then wouldn't the force be in the opposite direction for the 'not shown' connections resulting in a net force of zero magnitude ?

Comment: Those connections are completed at the two ends of the rotor outside or on the edge the field generated by the stator, so the largest part of the force generated is within the stator. Have you taken motors apart? If not you should do.

Comment: I think it would be a good idea to replace 'another' with 'one another' in the first line of your answer.

Comment: @Zam before you try to correct any possible error in my answer, you should correct the several that are in your question, such as "Where does the electrons flow to" should be "where do the electrons flow to"...

Comment: Actually, I wasn't pointing out any errors, in the first place. It's just that, it took me a while before I understood that you were actually referring to the circles already shown in the figure, when you mentioned 'paired with another'. Using 'one another' could make it obvious. That's all. You are free to point out errors in my question.